# How to check if textarea has white space and tap space

Tags: javascript

I want to run a script that will be checking if there is a white space and tap space with javascript. Please I need a help.

This is my code:

```
var textinputs = document.querySelector("#message");

textinputs.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (/\s/.test(e)) {
                $(btnSubmit).css("opacity", ".5");
                $(btnSubmit).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                console.log("block")
            } else {
                console.log("send");
                $(btnSubmit).css("opacity", "");
                $(btnSubmit).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
  });
```

My idea is to check if there is some white space or tap space if not enable the submit button

Comment: Use regular expressions for that.

Comment: "*I want*" is not a question; where are you stuck? What help do you need?

Comment: Which of the expression is that?

Comment: The problem there is only check the first condition which is the white space but if there is no space white it will still see  the first condition instead of else  @David Thomas